# Integrating Facebook connect with latest code

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I'm not very experienced with this facebook documentation.  I've been reading and reading and testing.

I'm in the process of trying to integrate with the newest system of facebook.

I've literally have spent hours reading the documentation, I somewhat understand the concept.  I don't have a clue from the documentation how to use the UID and access tokens then posting them to the database via php.

All the implementation tutorials and videos are from their old SDK systems. I've looked through and tried:(the cross domain files no longer are used according to documentation)

http://www.barattalo.it/facebook-connect-tutorial/
http://www.goldsteintech.com/facebook_connect/createNew_page.php

I am not familiar with advanced using of these programs, as per, all the research I've done.  Is there documentation that guides your step by step so I can understand how i can customize it and get it work functionally.

NOTE: The two older tutorials I've posted are ideally how I want it to work, I know how to change some of the information they get based from Facebooks documentation. Where to begin? I don't know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you provided clearer examples of what you're trying to accomplish.  Basically, you just call FB.login via Javascript, which invokes a callback with a response object that contains (among other things), an access_token.  Then you can pass that access_token to your server and have it make whatever API calls you want.

Comment: I somewhat understood that much, however, there are certain processes with facebooks php and such.  I can get the cookie to be posted and get some graph api calls but I'm unware how to take those and implement them with my current database